# Defining both post and get method under same request handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm using python to develop a web app.

I defined both "get" and "post" method in the same request handler to serve different purpose. That is, I use "get" method to present a form to user, and "post" method to handle the submitted form.

It works fine, but is this approach appropriate? Or should I better define get and post separately in different request handler? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is appropriate. According to the newest documentation you can even define post and get as functions outside request handler and just as other functions in your module and that's a way I would choose since it eliminates problems that can happen when instanciating request handlers.

If starting a new app from scratch I probably would try to put my get and post function outside of request handler with the new python 2.7 runtime that according to docs supports that.

Comment: "eliminates problems that can happen when instanciating request handlers" - say what?

Comment: I mean that creating less objects is more efficient if you agree. I had problem with initialization of request handlers when I suppose I can do without my own `def initialize` that some request handlers do. If it does the init code for every request then I can have a problem if I put expensive code for initialization where I mean to say creating less objects is better.

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem specific to request handler classes. If you do expensive initialization, it will take time and resources, period.

Comment: Maybe the advantage with putting the functions outside of the handlers is not so great as I though but it surely looks neat, makes it less code and DRY. I found that I couldn't use session object in initialize. Is is that I'm doing it wrong or just logical that I can't use a session object in the initilization?

Comment: I disagree - grouping handlers by URL makes perfect sense. As to using the session in the initialize method, that depends what you're using for sessions, and what you were trying to do.